# Where do PEAR packages normally get installed?

Tags: php, pear

I am using a Debian squeeze server. I have installed PEAR using `aptitude install php-pear`. This created a directory `/usr/share/php/PEAR`.

I installed some PEAR packages including Phing. I installed the Phing files using `pear install --alldeps phing/phing` and the files showed up in `/usr/share/php/phing`.

But shouldn't PEAR packages (under normal circumstances) be put in `/usr/share/php/PEAR`? When I run

```
pear config-get php_dir
```

I get "`/usr/share/php`". Have I got something configured wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
/usr/share/php/
```

is correct for Debian.

```
/usr/share/php/PEAR
```

itself contains classes for PEAR itself.

The reason for using `/usr/share/php` is that the `pear` CLI tool is an installer that installs libraries (or applications) for PHP - choosing `php` is thus correct.

Comment: PEAR was not meant for this. But you could try with a custom config that you pass with the -c parameter - but that one does not support relative paths.

Answer (score 25):

**Yes, that is the correct directory on Debian, and Ubuntu**.

Regardless of which O/S you are using, you can find the correct install directory by running: `pear config-get php_dir` via a console. And you get full directory path.

For example, with XAMPP application on Microsoft Window you have to go to XAMPP installation directory path `<<XAMPP Installation folder path>>/bin` and use `./pear config-get php_dir` which lead to execute the binary file using current location and do the same job.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Not only does it show a non-specific OS solution, it also compensates for the situation where an admin configures PEAR to be located in a non-default location.

Answer (score 2):

in case php is installed in /usr/local/php

pear is here:

/usr/local/php/lib/php

Answer (score 1):

On my 64-bit Ubuntu system, the pear packages are installed to `/usr/share/php/PEAR/`,
but I do not know how to change the pear install path. Maybe you can configure this somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Mac OSX Lion.
I installed pear in `/usr/lib/php/pear`

So the data also be installed there.

Answer (score 1):

On my installation of Debian PEAR is located here:

```
/usr/local/lib/php
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there, in case you have pear installed in a round-about way:

```
cd /
find . -type d -name pear
```

For example, I was using MAMP on one of my local machines and it was in a really weird place.

Comment: This helped. Im using cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CPanel to install them they're much likely to be located in

```
./opt/cpanel/ea-php{VERSION}/root/usr/share/pear
```